# How to fix this error 1004? Rewrite the line

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following line of code in VBA:

```
Range("A40:A64").Formula = "=IF(index(optional_processes,row()-39)=0;"";optional_processes,row()-39))"
```

Without the `if-statement`, some cells display `0`. I want these `0`to be blanks. That's what the `if-statement` should do. I think it gives the application or object-defined error because of the double quotation marks in the statement. How can I this get blank cells instead of `0`?

Comment: You have a couple of answers below but what you need to specify is do you want to catch errors in formula separate to a `0` value? So if its a `0` value, you want an empty cell but what do you want if there is a formula error? do you still want this to set an empty value in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you local Excel uses `;` (semicolon) as parameter separator in formulas, when writing a formula with VBA, you have to use `,` (comma)

Beside this, there are some more issues with the formula:

- You are missing a `index` at the `else`-part
- Use `""""` rather than `""` like Kresimir suggests
- Use an `ISERROR` like Kiran writes in his first suggestion

I think this will work:

```
Range("A40:A64").Formula = "=IF(isError(index(optional_processes,row()-39)),"""",index(optional_processes,row()-39))"
```

Comment: Also, when writing `""` in side of your formula, embrace `""` with double quotes from both sides. so instead of `Range("A40:A64").Formula = "=IF(index(optional_processes,row()-39)=0;"";optional_processes,row()-39))"` , try `Range("A40:A64").Formula = "=IF(index(optional_processes,row()-39)=0,"""",optional_processes,row()-39))"`

Comment: I've tried both it with the comma's and quatation marks, but i still get the error.

Comment: Added some things to my answer (mainly what Nick and Kiran suggests) to make it more complete

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Range("A40:A64").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(index(optional_processes,row()-39)),'',index(optional_processes,row()-39))"
```

OR

```
Range("A40:A64").Formula = "=IF(index(optional_processes,row()-39)=0,"""",index(optional_processes,row()-39))"
```